# Why postgres is returning additional backslash in a simple query

Tags: node.js, postgresql, pgadmin

So in my node code postgres query is returning double quotes when it's returning its values.

[image: Postgres Problem in query in nodejs]

As opposed to the query at pgAdmin.

[image: Postgres at pgAdmin]

I already tried to solve it using regex but this attempt was innefective. So if anyone had a problem like this and could help me, I would be glad.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's better to share code instead of images.

Comment: It's likely there are no extra quotes, it's just how the string is being displayed. How are you printing `values` in node? And by "returning double quotes" do you mean two single quotes?

Answer (score 0):

There are neither quotes nor extra back slashes *in* the string. They are part of the string *representation* as literal.

Try `console.log(value)` - or even directly `console.log('/\\w/g')` - and you'll see the output is `/\w/g` as expected.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, after a lot of reading and researching, I managed to discover that because a backslash character is a special character it will create some problems around its implementation in regex, because it is not permitted to have a lone backslash stored in a variable for example.

This would never work stored inside a variable because the backslash have to be escaped.

/\w+/ig
Javascript will transform it automatically to be able to perform.
/\w+/ig

When reading
[RegExp - Javascript](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ypuja.png) documentation, I came across an interesting statement, the RegExp function will recognize and use a double slash regex, thankfully!

So I just adapted my regex to split it's statement from it's flags and mount it again using RegExp.

Below is the code that I used to solve this problem

```
  // Getting values from postgres
  const values = (await pgConn.admRead.query(clientQuery)).rows[0].value || [];

  // Splitting regex ( values: /\w/g )
  const valuesSplit = values.split('/');   // RESULT -> ['', w, g]
  
  // Removing first array item when it's empty
  if (valuesSplit[0].length === 0) {
    valuesSplit.shift();
  }

  // Creating regex from splitted array
  const regexOperation = new RegExp(valuesSplit[0], valuesSplit[1]);

  // Executing replace function
  const messageMasked = message.replace(regexOperation, '*');
  return messageMasked;
```